# Avoiding pandas chained selection

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to determine "best practice" to do the following without incurring a `SettingWithCopyWarning`.  I'm using python 2.7 and pandas 15.2

What I want to do is subselect a dataframe and then use this selection as a new dataframe, without risking modification to the original.  Here's an example of what I'm doing:

```
import pandas as pd

def select_blue_cars(df):
    """Returns a new dataframe of blue cars"""
    return df[df['color'] == 'blue']

cars = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['blue', 'blue', 'red'], 'make': ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Ford']})
blue_cars = select_blue_cars(cars)
blue_cars['price'] = 10000
```

The above generates a `SettingWithCopyWarning` in current pandas but otherwise behaves as I want it to (ie. the `cars` df has not been modified).

- What is the best way to implement `select_blue_cars` so that the subsequent code doesn't trigger this warning?
- Should I be using `.copy()` everywhere?

  ```
  return df[df['color'] == 'blue'].copy()
  ```
- (Aside) What's the performance of `copy()` like?

Eventually I'd like to chain simple transform functions like `select_blue_cars`:

```
blue_fords = select_fords(select_blue_cars(cars))
```

**Edit:** Having thought about this a bit more I think that I'm looking for a single transform which selects a copy from the dataframe without explicitly calling `.copy()`.  That way I can write functions to do little transformations on the df and chain them.

Transposition for example `df.T` gives a new dataframe.  There's no need to call `.copy()`.

```
df2 = df.T
df2 = df.T.copy()  # no need
```

It looks like, in the case of selection, `.copy()` is required for this pattern.

Comment: settingwithcopywarning is to alert you that you may be modifying a copy of the data frame.  Is this warning from the line `blue_cars['price'] = 10000`?  You should try using blue_cars.loc instead.  You don't need the copy anywhere

Comment: You should return a `copy()` if that is your explicit intention, the warning is just advising you that the function may not be doing what you think.

Comment: I just tried your code and did not get the warning.  Exactly which line was it?

Comment: It's the final line where I set the price @JohnE .  The pandas version matters.  I'm getting the warning on 15.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you get around the `SettingWithCopyWarning` depends a bit on how long you plan on keeping the subset around. If you just want to briefly look at the price within a particular colour and then return to the overall dataframe, the suggestions JohnE has given are pretty good. If you actually want to keep the subset around and perform a bunch of separate analyses on it, then what I usually do is subset with `.loc` and explicitly copy, e.g.:

```
subset = df.loc[df['condition'] > 5, :].copy()
```

In your code, this would be:

```
import pandas as pd

def select_blue_cars(df):
    """Returns a new dataframe of blue cars"""
    return df.loc[df['color'] == 'blue', :].copy()

cars = pd.DataFrame({'color': ['blue', 'blue', 'red'], 'make': ['Ford', 'BMW', 'Ford']})
blue_cars = select_blue_cars(cars)
blue_cars['price'] = 10000
```

Comment: This is what I thought I'd need to do was hoping someone would put me right!  Something feels wrong about calling 2 methods to do this.  As I put in my edit, `cars.T` or similar transformations doesn't require `.copy()` on top of it.  Thanks for your response

Comment: Will using .copy() not actually copy twice in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I think this remains one of the more confusing parts of pandas.  You are actually asking 2 or 3 questions and the answers may be less simple than you'd think.  Consequently, I'll make the simplifying assumption that you'll just keep everything in one dataset (if not, it's not that big a deal though), and give a simple answer.

What you want to do (in pseudocode):

`price = 10000 if color == blue`

The simplest way to do this is actually with numpy `where()`:

`cars['price'] = np.where( cars['color'] == 'blue', 10000, np.nan )`

```
  color  make  price
0  blue  Ford  10000
1  blue   BMW  10000
2   red  Ford    NaN
```

You can also nest `where()` so it's really very powerful and simple method for conditional setting like this.  You can also use `ix/loc/iloc` (though you need to create an empty column for 'price' first):

`cars.ix[ cars.color == 'blue', 'price' ] = 10000`

And to briefly address the chained indexing warning, what it's mostly saying is don't try to do too much on the left hand side when setting values:

`df[ df.y > 5 ]['x'] = df['z']`

this is OK though:

`df['x'] = df[ df.y > 5 ]['z']`

Because the result of chained indexing may by a copy rather than reference, which will cause the former to fail but not the latter.  You can also get around this by using `ix/loc/iloc`.

Comment: Your answer is helpful as it shows that I probably can't do what I want with a single dataframe method.  I don't want to modify the original dataframe in this case, I want to select part of it and use it independently.  Now maybe the bigger point is that pandas shouldn't be used in this manner and I should refactor things so that I am just modifying a single dataframe!